# What is the Hong Kong craft beer scene these days?

Tags: micropub

When I lived in Hong Kong a few years back I enjoyed several interesting microbrewed beers and a small but enthusiastic beer scene. I still think about the much-missed [Belgos East](http://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/restaurant/quarry-bay-belgos-east-mussels-more/7578), which had a whole suite of Belgian ales on tap. What's available these days?

Comment: That's very interesting. I would like to know about it too.

Answer (score 1):

Craft Beer Association of Hong Kong
http://www.cbahk.org/

Link to several of the craft brewers in Hong Kong:
http://www.cbahk.org/brewers

"Hong Kong's Best Craft Beer Bars"
http://beertopiahk.com/pages/bars